# How do I achieve such gradient / fill in Figma?

Tags: gradient, figma

I've come across this UI element

[image]

I tried to copy.. and realized I couldn't.

1. Do the semicircles use some sort of gradient?
2. Is it possible to apply such gradient in Figma?

Comment: it looks like simple linear gradients to me. What have you tried? Why can't you copy it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it in Figma. These are actually just simple linear gradients from top to bottom, and the semi-circles are actually regular circles.

The top color is close to the one in the background, and the bottom color is either the same as the background or just 100% transparent.

See below image, the objects are selected hence the blue outline.

[image]

And this is the same image when it's not selected:

[image]